# REACT - Erro datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, react

Bom dia! Estou tentando utilizar componentes de datepicker no React. Estou usando materialize, mas até mesmo o componente do mesmo está gerando o mesmo erro. Atualmente estou tentando utilizar o react-jqueryui-datepicker.

Nesse trecho:

```
render () {
        return <input
            type="text"
            ref="datepicker"
            {...this.props}
            />
    }
```

é gerado o erro:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (17:9)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

Já percebi que qualquer componente que tenha esse esquema de chaves + ... gera esse erro, como mostrado: `{...this.props}`

Estou iniciando no React, vocês já se depararam com esse erro? Eu estaria referenciando algo incorretamente?

Comment: @t-borges você está usando o react-cli?

Comment: Estou sim, William

Comment: @t-borges pelo erro parece algum problema ou com o `import` do plugin ou algum problema no `webpack`. Atualize sua pergunta com o import do date-picker e seu webpack.config

Answer (score 0):

Tente utilizar o componente como diz na documentação importando o componente e referenciando o mesmo.

```
import DatePicker from 'react-jqueryui-datepicker';

function changeHandler(e){
    //e is a momentJS DateTime instance
}

 <DatePicker 
    onChange={changeHandler} />
```